# Rundeck stuck running

Tags: cron, rundeck

I am using rundeck 2.10.1 (latest version) backed database is mssql.
* I am using sqljdbc4.2, because bug that occurs on sqljdbc4.1

Sometimes (it's not consistent), I am faced with jobs in rundeck that stuck, until I kill them, or restart rundeck.
The job itself is done (I can see it in my job's logs), and even if i tried to put timeout in the rundeck job, I can see in the rundeck logs that timeout occurs, it stops the connection, but the job is still running.

Tried look in the rundeck jobs logs, and in rundeck logs - can`t see anything... also tried look for it in google and didnt find anything interesting.

There is a solution for this?

* I installed rundeck on server X, but it runs scripts on server Y if it matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue; It is not a rundeck problem, rather than a client issue in my case: I had a job on Rundeck to stop/start/status services on a Linux client from Rundeck; the job executed successfully, yet it kept stuck running.

Checked the client logs, found a running process causing loops on the system [in my case, a running background process of a snmp python script] seems preventing session closure with rundeck.

Comment: I seem to have a similar problem. If I uncomment this command in my script `/usr/bin/pg_createcluster --start`, Rundeck stucks running when executing this script. What do I need to look for to try to work around this problem?